# C# MVC store image in database and return to view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, image

Scope - I am uploading a file (image) to a **sqldb** and need to return this image to the view when I load the page.

The file is saved to the db as a `byte[]` with file name and content type, so i dont think the problem is here.

I have previously returned the file as a **Base64 string** which was fine but want to avoid this due to inflated dom size.

I have the following method to return the file but don't know how to insert it. I don't want to use an AJAX call from the view, I want the MVC approved solution to serve the content.

```html
public FileContentResult getFile(byte[] fileBytes, string fileMime, string fileName) {
return File(fileBytes, fileMime, fileName);
} 

public ActionResult Show(string id) {
  using (var db = new DbContext) {
      var a = getFile(db.File.Content, db.File.Mime, db.File.Name);
      var page = db.Pages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
      PageViewModel page = new PageViewModel {
                        PageContent = page.PageContent,
                        PageImage = a
      }
  }
}
```

(I know the code here is sketchy as the `db.file` stuff wont work but its just an example so you know what I mean.)

Comment: I know that's not what you're asking for, but from personal experience I recommend to avoid storing actual images to the database. It'll bloat database size and make ops life complicated. Better have a CDN, save images there and have a url to that image in database.

Comment: I originally had a scope to make it portable so i thought sticking it in a database makes it easy to move if needed. Not worked much with adding files to the server though, so i will have to look into this instead i think.